# python pandas: trying to reference data from another column's previous month end

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, indexing, offset

I am trying to create a column in a dataframe that references the value in another column from the previous month end. Like this...

```html
Date         SD SD.prevmo
02/29/00 0.0312 0.0312
03/01/00 0.0304 0.0312
03/02/00 0.0293 0.0312
03/03/00 0.0287 0.0312
  
03/28/00 0.0502 0.0312
03/29/00 0.0526 0.0312
03/30/00 0.0537 0.0312
03/31/00 0.0556 0.0556
04/03/00 0.0507 0.0556
04/04/00 0.0532 0.0556
04/05/00 0.0536 0.0556
```

The DateOffset functionality including BMonthEnd() seems to have the answer in it so I must be butchering something that's not terribly complex.

```
df.ix[df.index.is_month_end==True, SD.prevmo] = df[SD]
df.ix[df.index.is_month_end==False, SD.prevmo] = ???
```

Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you set the values for `is_month_end==True` with `df['SD']`, you can full `NAs` with `ffill` methiod - which forward fills the values.

```
In [10]: df.ix[df.index.is_month_end==True, 'SD.prevmo'] = df['SD']
In [11]: df['SD.prevmo'].fillna(method='ffill')
Out[11]:
Date
2000-02-29    0.0312
2000-03-01    0.0312
2000-03-02    0.0312
2000-03-03    0.0312
2000-03-28    0.0312
2000-03-29    0.0312
2000-03-30    0.0312
2000-03-31    0.0556
2000-04-03    0.0556
2000-04-04    0.0556
2000-04-05    0.0556
Name: SD.prevmo, dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks John - I do see that works as a stand alone, but as part of a loop over a bunch of dfs, it isn't happening - the NaNs are still there. Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: disregard...  df['SD.prevmo'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True) was the missing piece. thanks again John Galt.